# php query database print to html table with headers

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have never programmed anything in php before and haven't touched html in 10 years. I could use some help. I am querying a postgresql database using php. I am trying to display my query results in a table format with headers like this:

```
first_name   last_name   employee_id
tom          jones       111
bob          barker      112
bill         davis       113
```

Sample code I am trying to get to work correctly:

```
echo("<table border=2");
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($line as $col_value => $row_value) {
        echo("<tr><td>$col_value</td><td>$row_value</td></tr>\n");
    }
}
echo("</table>");
```

My formatting is being displayed like this:

```
first_name tom
last_name jones
employee_id 111
first_name bob
last_name barker
employee_id 112
first_name bill
last_name davis
employee_id 113
```

As you can see I am storing my query in an associative array.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might want to look into [Symfony](http://symfony.com/), if you've a programming background but are unfamiliar with PHP. Symfony2 combined with Doctrine2 is an *excellent* PHP framework.

Comment: Looking at it again, my answer fixes an html formatting issue that was there but the data would still be displayed like your example.  I saw the missing > and thought that was it...my mistake.    Dirk's answer looks like it will get you what except for the column headers which you would have to deal with manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo("<table border=2><tr><td>first_name</td><td>last_name</td><td>employee_id</td></tr>");
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo("<tr>");
    foreach ($line as $col_value => $row_value) {
        echo("<td>$row_value</td>");
    }
    echo("</tr>\n");
}
echo("</table>");
```

Or:

```
echo("<table border=2><tr><td>first_name</td><td>last_name</td><td>employee_id</td></tr>");
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo("<tr><td>".$line[0]."</td><td>".$line[1]."</td><td>".$line[2]."</td></tr>\n");
}
echo("</table>");
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch that is very close to what I am looking for. Do you have any ideas on how I could dynamically create the table column headers rather than hard coding them in?

Comment: `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.\`COLUMNS\` C WHERE table_name = '<your table name>'` ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you might be missing a bracket on the opening table tag:

Try changing this:

```
echo("<table border=2");
```

to this:

```
echo('<table border="2">');
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: I wish it were that easy ; ).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "<table width=100% border="1">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {  
  $id= $row["id"]; 
  $f_name= $row["f_name"]; 
  echo "<tr><td>";
  echo $id;
  echo"</td>";
  echo"<td>";
  echo $f_name;
  echo"</tr>";
 } 
echo"</table>";
?>
```

try this may help

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<table>\n";
echo("<table border=2");
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value => $row_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
    break;
}
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```